# Include a vscode language extension in a package

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm wondering if there's a way to have a NPM package also include a language extension to support its use. For example, I'm seeing some neat work on using tagged template literals as HTML templates (i.e. [here](https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2019/jsx-like-syntax-for-tagged-template-literals/)), and I also know there's VSCode extensions that allow you to treat specific tagged templates as embedded languages (i.e. [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html)). I'm wondering if it's possible to have these both included in the same package, making it easy for consumers of a package to include the necessary syntax/semantic highlighting out of the box?